# How do I deal with an accumulation of Flurries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, flurry

I have an iPhone app that has a relatively simple Flurry configuration installed.  I notice that the Flurry files ("flurryResponseNNNNN...") seem to build up and are never deleted (at least not going back over 3 weeks).

Now, it is getting to be late enough in the year where we begin expect some accumulation here in Minnesota, but I'm not anxious for this much this early.

Is there some Flurry setting that controls the number of files (or total size or whatever) that Flurry retains, or do I need to manage this directly in my app?

### Added:

The files are in the Documents directory.  They contain XML similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>body</key>
    <data>
    </data>
    <key>headers</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Connection</key>
        <string>close</string>
        <key>Content-Length</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>Content-Type</key>
        <string>application/octet-stream</string>
        <key>Date</key>
        <string>Wed, 14 Sep 2011 19:41:25 GMT</string>
        <key>Server</key>
        <string>nginx</string>
    </dict>
    <key>statusCode</key>
    <integer>200</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should say that I discovered that these files are diagnostic logs, turned on by a setting when starting up Flurry.  (I forget the specific setting and don't have the code at hand here, but it's fairly obvious when you go looking for it.)  Turn off that setting and they go away (or at least no more are generated).

Answer (score 0):

I've used Flurry before and never seen these files. Where are they being stored; if it's in the cache or temp folder then i wouldn't' worry about them.

Do you see flurry working correctly when you go to your app's website?

Can you tell us more about your flurry configuration? What analytics are you bring to record?

NB I certainly wouldn't want to start manually deleting files from inside your app!

Comment: They're in the Documents directory.

Comment: They looks like some sort of Flurry communication status log. I've never seen them before. I'd contact Flurry's technical team and ask directly! You might also check that you have the latest version of the libraries - it might have been a bug that's already been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {   
   [FlurryAPI startSession:@"YOUR APP KEY"];
   [FlurryAPI logEvent:@"Application Started"];
   [FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnCloseEnabled:FALSE];
   [FlurryAPI setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled:FALSE];
}
```