# iPhone app storage growing

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, flurry

I had a quick search for this but unfortunately couldn't find any answer.

My iPhone app is still underdevelopment. I just noticed from my iPhone's Settings->General->Usage, that this app is taking over 900MB of space. I'm shocked and don't understand why.

I'm not saving any downloaded images, strings or any kind of large data base. Original app size is < 10MB. It contains only a few images added to project folder.

I'm suing `NSUserDafaults` to save a few parameters. (Used for simple app/user settings)

Other External/3rd Party Libraries, I used are:

- SBJson
- Amazon Web Services (for uploading images)
- Flurry
- KTPhotoBrowser
- ASIHTTPRequest (I know this has deprecated. So
  far its working good for me and in after the first release, I'm
  planning to replace it with any best alternate)
- Facebook
- Twitter (not integrated yet)

Any ideas what could be the reason? Am I missing something or doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I deleted the app and re-installed it. Now after first launch, it takes 13.2MB where 7.4MB is app size and 5.8MB are taken by Documents and Data. It seems that the storage being used increases with time.

Comment: 900mb?! There's definitely a problem somewhere. That's insane. Try running the app in the simulator and have a look at the app documents folder on your mac.

Comment: are you using TestFlight for distribution ? might be crash reports accumulating

Comment: @LouWeed. No I'm not using TestFlight.

Comment: @LiamGeorgeBetsworth I checked the sizes of app in all versions of simulators and they are all under 10MB :\

Comment: You could also use iExplorer to check the documents folder on the device. (Or just print out the contents yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay! I had a thorough lookup into the problem and found that its XCode responsible for causing the app to take so much storage space.

I'm not certain what goes on under the hood but when the app is connected to XCode and is running, the storage size would increase. But if its not connected to XCode, and run the app, it would run normally and won't take any undesired storage.

I guess its because XCode might be saving logs/snap shots of app. I'm not sure.

So, it seems that my app is safe (Thank GOD!) and hope apple won't have any objections when I submit it for release.

@Yangfan Zhang: Flurry seems to be safe and is not responsible for the issue as haven't removed any of the mentioned libraries and done the investigation.

Comment: Thank you for answer brother...I was scratching my head as my app data size was continuously exceeding even in GBs , even in instruments I was not able to reproduce the increasing app size...But I am still not able to understand why it is happening with Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

If your app support above **iOS5** then you should remove **Twitter** and **SBJson** frameworks.

**ASIHTTPRequest** is also providing the image upload facility so you can also remove the **Amazon Web Services**.

**ASIHTTPRequest** has lot of files so identify the class which are not use in your app and you can also remove that files.For example zZip files if you are not using it.

Comment: Yes! the target is iOS5. Whats the alternate of SBJson then? And are you sure this could be because of SBJson? AWS sdk provides a very simple way of uploading images to the servers. In order to use ASIHttpRequest for that, I will have a create a lot of custom headers. So, I don't think thats a smart idea. Any ways, the app size is still just under 10MB.

Comment: For JSON parsing you can use NSJSONSerialization which is available iOS5 and above.

Comment: For twitter you can also user iOS Twitter framework.

Comment: if answer is helps to you then please +1 to it.

Comment: well... it doesn't solve the specific problem so... :|. But, i will try your suggestions and see if those are the real problems. Then will see.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a problem with a growing log file or something. Your app can't be 900MB when you're installing it or it would take about half an hour to transfer onto the phone.

You said that you have tried running the app in simulator, but have you actually looked in the documents directory for the culprit files?

If not:

1. Run the app in the simulator for a bit and act out normal behaviour.
2. Navigate to `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1*/Applications/` *iOS version you are running
3. Find your app there (it'll be weird characters) and check the `Documents` directory. This folder contains anything you are storing within the app.

Depending on what version of OSX you're running (Lion or later), your personal Library directory may be hidden. You can unhide it by typing `/usr/bin/chflags nohidden ~/Library` in the command line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes! this is exactly where I checked. The Document folder is empty. And TheWeiredBunchOfChars->Library->Preferences contains a plist which contains all strings I have been saving using NSUserDefaults. And surprisingly, the storage grows in device only. I have iOS 6.0.1 on my device.

Comment: Then my only suggestion is to look carefully at every download/data creation point in your app. It could be that something is constantly downloading.

Comment: hmmm... sounds creepy :\

Answer (score 0):

Flurry may leave some files under Document directory. Those files will accumulate over time. Please take a look at this post [How do I deal with an accumulation of Flurries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731335/how-do-i-deal-with-an-accumulation-of-flurries)

Comment: Incorrect! I had a thorough lookup at the issue and found out that its XCode responsible for the problem. Doesn't actually seems to be a problem though. Have a look at my answer that I'm gonna post in a few minutes.